# PHP variable from another file

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 files, one named client.php and one named habbo3.js. Inside the client.php there is something called "connection.info.host": that usually needs to have an IP.

However I'm trying to use it as a variable and get the IP from the JavaScript file. I tried doing it like down below but I'm getting an error on chrome developer tool

> client:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: price1 is not defined(anonymous function) @ client:21

My client.php file: http://pasted.co/0a5a803e

My habbo3.js file:

```
var price1 = 123.456.789;
var price2 = 222.222.222;
```

The numbers above are just false numbers but should be replaced with my VPS IP address. Any solution for this guys?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load `habbo3.js` with this line:

```
<link src="http://.../habbo3.js">
```

You should replace it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../habbo3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
client:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: price1 is not defined

Comment: I already tried that but look at the error above, this is what I get. and the habbo3.js file looks like this: var price1 = 5.254.102.151;
var price2 = 5.254.102.151;